# Set a condition to swap an image when it takes too long to load

Tags: javascript, image

I want to make a condition when an image takes more than 2 seconds to load, swap that image with another one. Now, I have a `.on('error')` function to check the image url, if the url is bad, swap that image. But, what if an image is taking too long to load? Is there a callback I can use when certain images take more than 2 seconds to load?

```
        $('img').on('load', function() {
          //do things here
    })
      .on('error', function() {
        $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("/broken-image")');
        $(this).parent().addClass('img-not-found');
      })
      .each(function() {
        if(this.complete) {
          console.log('completed here');
        }else {
        $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("/broken-image")');
        $(this).parent().addClass('img-not-found');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you put something in a setTimeout function that's set to two seconds. First thing it does is check for complete. If complete is true, just end the function and move on like it was never called. If complete is false, run through your image change function.

Comment: thought about using `setTimeout`, didn't implement right. tried couple times, didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it work - using the `onload` function of the image to determine that the image is actually done loading:

```
var imageElement = document.getElementById("myImage");
var isImageLoaded = false;

imageElement.onload = function() {
    isImageLoaded = true;
}

setTimeout(function() {
    if (isImageLoaded === false) {
        //2 seconds passed, no dice on the image!
    }
}, 2000);
```